# How can I center my div in the @media query after applying flex-direction?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I tried putting the `banner-content-container` in the center after using `flex-direction:column;` in the media query, but it doesn't work. It centers normally but when it gets to the 776px max-width, It doesn't center the div.

Here's my code:

```css
.banner-content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:776px) {
  .banner-content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner-content-container">
    <div class="content contexts1">
      <h3>01. Mobile conductive</h3>
      <p>Smart optimization of RWD design.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content contexts2">
      <h3>02. User Interface</h3>
      <p>Brilliant UI/UX creative designs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content contexts3">
      <h3>03. Affordable</h3>
      <p>Our offers dont break the bank.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `flex-direction` flips your main axis.

When in row mode, horizontal alignment is achieved via `flex-direction` and vertical alignment with `align-items`. In your breakpoint, the opposite is now true.

```css
.banner-content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:776px) {
  .banner-content-container {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner-content-container">
    <div class="content contexts1">
      <h3>01. Mobile conductive</h3>
      <p>Smart optimization of RWD design.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content contexts2">
      <h3>02. User Interface</h3>
      <p>Brilliant UI/UX creative designs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content contexts3">
      <h3>03. Affordable</h3>
      <p>Our offers dont break the bank.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note also that you don't need `display: flex` within your media query; it's already set in the statement above, media queries don't reset properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, But the items aren't aligned directly under each other.

Comment: They're centred based on the width of their content. You'll need to set an equal width on each item to avoid that.